# Is there a way to detect device vibration in Javascript/Cordova/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, vibration

I am working on a cordova app that makes use of the accelerator data. But I need the app to be aware of acceleration originating due to phone vibration, in order to account for it.

I understand that there exists support to *create* vibrations in HTML5 via the vibration API, but is there a way to fire/listen to events corresponding to vibration triggered by some other application or the OS?

Comment: Frequency of vibration typically about 180Hz. If you don't need frequencies above let say 100Hz cut them with lo-pass filter. Alternatively you can make a trick by measuring frequency of vibration by triggering it; this will enable you to detect frequency in accelerometer data and drop that segment from stream

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the cordova accelerometer plugin (cordova-plugin-device-motion). you can add it to your cordova mobile project using

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-motion`
You can find out more from [here]: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device-motion/